# I can't connect to internet through wifi using Xubuntu

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, internet, realtek-wireless, d-link

Everytime i try to connect to internet using wifi i type the password, Xubuntu tries to connect for a little while and then asks me the password again. I'm using a D-Link modem/router.

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8171] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1467]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8171] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1467]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se

Comment: See what you were supposed to do? EDIT your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can install another driver. You need to be connected to internet by wire.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: I did this and still doesn't work.

Comment: Then it is some trouble specific to Xubuntu. I saw another question with this problem. It is a bug. You can report it. If you install Lubuntu or Ubuntu, it should work.

Comment: Anyone else can help? It's really important to me to get this working.